# MVC Details page not showing any data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am pretty new to MVC and I am building a small contacts app. I have created the database and the Index page displays the data for the DB fine. The Issue I have is my details page. It will display the titles but wont show any data.

Here is my Model:

```
namespace BCM.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Address3 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Telephone1 { get; set; }
        public string Telephone2 { get; set; }
        public string Telephone3 { get; set; }
        public string Telephone4 { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Email2 { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Details()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
        if (contact == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(contact);
    }
```

And here is a section of my View:

```
@model BCM.Models.Contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Surname)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CompanyName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CompanyName)
        </dd>
```

This is what my details page shows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z1wH.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Worked out what I was missing and have posted the answer below

Comment: I don't understand why do you use [HttpPost] attribute when you are trying to display your model. You must use [HttpGet] Method instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work out what I was missing. It was to do with my @Html.ActionLink not passing through the Id